# Will ng-repeat bind my custom directive DOM elements when they get reloaded?

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-repeat that lists users and uses a custom directive.

My custom directive has some event handlers like click handlers etc.

This vm.UserList will get modified every time a drop down list value is changed in the UI.  My question is, will the event handlers get updated whenever the UserList is modified by a drop down list?

The dropdownlist on change will make a remote API request and then set the JSON result of the users to the value of the UserList.

```
<div ng-repeat="u in vm.UserList">
    <div><div my-custom-directive user-id="{u.id}" >{u.email}</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. According to [angularjs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates):

> ngRepeat uses $watchCollection to detect changes in the collection.
>   When a change happens, ngRepeat then makes the corresponding changes
>   to the DOM:
>
> 1- When an item is added, a new instance of the template is added to the
>   DOM.
>
> 2-When an item is removed, its template instance is removed from
>   the DOM.
>
> 3-When items are reordered, their respective templates are
>   reordered in the DOM.

So your directive gets added to the page including all of the event handlers.